# How to make program react on composite size change in GWT?

Tags: events, gwt, resize, composite

I want to implement something similar to geographic map widget. I made a `Composite`, consisting of motionless `AbsolutePanel` (outer) and moving `AbsolutePanel` inside (inner). The user will move the inner panel with the mouse and it will determine which of its tiles should be requested from the server.

So, I want it to react when the outer panel resizes. Also, I want to know its size when this happens. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd look into extending [`ResizeComposite`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ResizeComposite.html) instead of `Composite`. `ResizeComposite` is basically a subclass that propagates the resize event to its children. Once you're extending that class, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627911/gwt-how-to-get-new-size-when-doing-onresize-in-splitlayoutpanel) for ideas of how to get the new size.